# How can I get sum values using a SQL case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the query shown here to sum of financial target first statement(expd) is working fine it's showing sum where `socode` is not equal to 29 and 42. But the
second statement I want to get sum only where `socode = 42` and 29 and 20 but its giving 0.00 value while 29 and 42 having its own value.

```
select 
   isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2),
           SUM(CASE WHEN SoCode <> 42 and SoCode <> 29 and SoCode <> 20 
                       THEN (Financialtarget)/100000 ELSE 0 END)), 0) as expd,
   isnull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2),
           SUM(CASE WHEN (SoCode = 29) and (SoCode = 42)  
                      THEN (Financialtarget)/100000 ELSE 0 END)), 0) as expd1
from 
    MPR 
where 
    month <= 7 
    and mpryear = '2014-15' 
    and Division = '12'
```

Thanks

Comment: Please format the code.

Answer (score 3):

`expd1` is 0 because the condition `(SoCode=29) and (SoCode=42)` is always wrong. It should be using `OR` like `(SoCode=29) OR (SoCode=42) OR (SOCode=20)` instead of using `AND`

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),
    SUM(CASE WHEN SoCode <> 42 AND SoCode <> 29 AND SoCode <> 20 
        THEN (Financialtarget)/100000 
        ELSE 0 END)),0) AS expd, 
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),
        SUM(CASE WHEN (SoCode = 29) OR (SoCode = 42) OR (SOCode = 20) 
        THEN (Financialtarget)/100000 
        ELSE 0 END)),0) AS expd1
FROM MPR 
WHERE month <= 7 AND mpryear = '2014-15' AND Division = '12'
```

Alternatively you can also use `IN`

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),
    SUM(CASE WHEN SoCode <> 42 AND SoCode <> 29 AND SoCode <> 20 
        THEN (Financialtarget)/100000 
        ELSE 0 END)),0) AS expd, 
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),
        SUM(CASE WHEN SoCode IN (29,42,20)
        THEN (Financialtarget)/100000 
        ELSE 0 END)),0) AS expd1
FROM MPR 
WHERE month <= 7 AND mpryear = '2014-15' AND Division = '12'
```